# division operator error in standard ml and Cpn tools

Tags: sml, cpn-tools

I'm new in standard ml and I'm using cpn tools.I have some constants:

```
val PHY=120;
val RB=1;
```

I want to calculate PHY/RB then I have created
`val x=PHY/RB;` in cpn tools
but it has error when I write divide operator what is the problem?
please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer division operator in SML is called `div`.

```
val x = PHY div RB
```